# Error 500 retrieving a rss feed

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to retrieve a rss feed from this URL: http://www.8a.nu/rss/Main.aspx?UserId=19212&AscentType=0&ObjectClass=2&GID=3974d72911c05719152f0953e88cc2df

There is no problem if you point at that address with your browser, but I get a 500 error if I try to get the feed with file_get_contents. I've tried cURL as well with the same result.

I also tried to copy the result via wget and lynx without success.

Here you can see/test the script: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Qjrjay

Comment: Edit out the solution and paste as an answer. Then accept it when you can so it will show everyone in the future how you fixed it. Unless you do so, despite being in the question, it will still tell everyone you haven't "found" the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem was the user agent sniffing.

For a quick workaround I've added on top of my script:

```
 ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
 ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
 ini_set("memory_limit", "10000M");
```

It works now!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
$baseurl = "http://www.8a.nu/rss/Main.aspx?";
$query = urlencode("UserId=19212&AscentType=0&ObjectClass=2&GID=3974d72911c05719152f0953e88cc2df");
$final_uri = $baseurl.$query;
$response = file_get_contents($final_uri);
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo $response;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Don't know why, but econding the URL you get a different feed.